# how can I migrate to AS3 with code like this "l = new LoadVars ();"

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash

i am a beginner. I'm starting to learn Adobe Flash. I followed the code on Google on AS2:

```js
l = new LoadVars();
l.onLoad = function(ok) {
ttl0=l.ttlslv0; atc0=l.atcslv0;
ttl1=l.ttlslv1; atc1=l.atcslv1;
};
l.sendAndLoad("http:localhost/getdata.php", l, "POST");
```

with php like this:

```html
<?php
include_once("koneksi.php");
$qr = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT title, article from $tabel");
$nr = 0;
while($kolom=mysqli_fetch_row($qr) )
{ 
$ttl=$kolom[0];
$atc=$kolom[1];
echo "&ttlslv$nr=$ttl&atcslv$nr=$atc";
$nr++;
}
echo "&nr=$nr&";
?>
```

with the results that I can specify "what row" and "what column" will I take.
can this be changed to AS3 with the same results?
I have difficulty studying AS3
anyone want to give me a solution? thanx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AS3 you use the [URLLoader class](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) to load text/binary data. To work with URL-encoded strings you need the [URLVariables class](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLVariables.html).

Something like that (not tested, no error handling either, just a common guideline):

```
// URLRequest instance holds various information
// about what, where and how you send.
var aRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest;

// URL address.
aRequest.url = "http://localhost/getdata.php";

// Request method (POST or GET mostly).
aRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

// URLLoader instance performs the requested operations:
// uploads the request and relevant data, reads the answer,
// and dispatches all the events about any status changes.
var aLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader;

// Tell the URLLoader that the answer is
// an URL-encoded text of key=value pairs.
aLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;

// This event handler function will be triggered
// upon successfully completed operation.
aLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onData);

// Start loading.
aLoader.load(aRequest);

// The COMPLETE event handler function.
function onData(e:Event):void
{
    // Unsubscribe from the event. For the most part it is
    // a GOOD idea NOT to re-use any network-related
    // class instances once they've done their job.
    // Just unsubscribe from all their events,
    // dismantle their data structures, purge
    // any references to them and let the
    // Garbage Collector do his job.
    aLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onData);

    // Retrieve the object that contains key=value pairs.
    var anAnswer:URLVariables = aLoader.data as URLVariables;

    // The data you wanted to get.
    trace(anAnswer.ttlslv0);
    trace(anAnswer.atcslv0);
    trace(anAnswer.ttlslv1);
    trace(anAnswer.atcslv1);
}
```

**UPD**: It seems that you are dealing with **escaped** text there. I composed a simple script that explains how it works:

```
import flash.net.URLVariables;

var V:URLVariables = new URLVariables;
var S:String = "a=1&b=2";

V.decode(S);
trace(V.a); // 1
trace(V.b); // 2

S = escape(S);
trace(S); // a%3D1%26b%3D2
trace(unescape(S)); // a=1&b=2

V.decode(S); // Error #2101
```

So, there are two options you can work on:

1. Figure out why server passes the escaped string and prevent it.
2. Load the server's answer as a plain text (**URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT** instead of **VARIABLES**) so the **URLLoader.data** will be just a simple **String**, then **unescape(...)** it if necessary and feed to the **URLVariables.decode(...)**.

Comment: I just tried this. and I get an error like this: Error: Error #2101: The String passed to URLVariables.decode() must be a URL-encoded query string containing name/value pairs.
 at Error$/throwError()
 at flash.net::URLVariables/decode()
 at flash.net::URLVariables()
 at flash.net::URLLoader/onComplete()

Comment: I successfully display the data with the script. but the problem is the data that appears in the form of encoded data. in the first column "ttlslv0 =" can be retrieved. but in the next column ttlslv1, atcslv0 and others, all become code like this: "% 0Attlslv0% 3D" so that the symbol "=" disappears and changes to% 3D. "% 0Attlslv0% 3D" is not considered a different variable from ttlslv0 but is entered as a value of ttlslv0.

Comment: is there any difference between encoder in as2 and as3? the "&" characters in as2 aren't changed and "=" doesn't change. but in order to run on as3, the "&" characters must be removed. and "=" change.

Comment: @Kholishudin I conducted a simple test and updated my answer.